# Jasmine date expect always returning false

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a test written in Jasmine test runner:

```
it("Expect 'due date' to be 14 days from today", function () {
    var dateNow = new Date();
    scope.dateOfService(dateNow);
    expect(scope.DueDate == new Date(dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate() + 14))).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

However this always returns false? Is there something I'm doing incorrect?

To 'debug' this I also ran:

```
expect(scope.DueDate).toBe(new Date(dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate() + 14)));
```

And this returns:

```
Expected Date(Tue Nov 11 2014 08:20:23 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)) to be Date(Tue Nov 11 2014 08:20:23 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dateNow = new Date();
scope.dateOfService(dateNow);
var dateReturned = new Date(scope.DueDate);
var dateAdd = new Date(dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate() + 14));
expect(dateReturned).toEqual(dateAdd);
```

The main point was to ensure it was `.toEqual` rather than `.toBe`.